# with "Games Folder" having stuck icons

Tags: windows-7, steam

Recently I installed Torchlight via Steam on my PC and tried to keep the shortcut in my Games Folder.

Instead, it make a blank icon (as in, default application icon) which doesn't launch the game and un-removable. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the icon?

Comment: This doesn't tell you how to remove it, but it does tell you how to add an actual working icon: http://forums.guru3d.com/showpost.php?s=380b0527659314a9c15d33d16f3aebbd&p=3380963&postcount=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've figured out how although I'm not sure if this is a thorough solution.

## 1 Keys in Registry Editor

It seems that the registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameUX

is related to the Games Folder. Inside, the key with a GUID name ({s-1-5 etc...} on mine) contained all the custom added games. I checked which one has the steam game's name (Torchlight) and removed it.

## 2 Removed from AppData

I went to:

> C:\Users\IvoryTower\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\GameExplorer
> and removed the folders which have the same GUID as the games you deleted from registry

I found this by searching the registry for Torchlight and then searching for the same in Windows Explorer..

Answer (score 0):

Reboot into Windows `Safe Mode` and you should be able to delete the shortcut.

If that does not work you can try some programs which force the removal of stuck files although I don't recommend that as a first step because the results can be unpredictable.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. Can you suggest a good 'stuck icon removal' tool?